# SharePoint 2010 and Advanced Conditional Formating

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

Has anyone been able to get the conditional formatting for work based on dates?

I want to apply formatting to a list item that was created more than 7 days ago.

I have exhausted my Google searching and nothing. This is the expression that seems others have used. But it's not working for me.

```
number(translate(substring-before(@Created,'T'),'-','')+7) >= 
    number(translate(substring-before($Today,'T'),'-',''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for XSL template matches;

```
<xsl:variable name="dateTime" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Created), 1033, 3)" />
<xsl:variable name="dateTimeCondensed" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Created), 1033, 2)" />
<xsl:variable name="date"  select="substring-before(substring-after($dateTime, ', '), ', ')" />
<xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before($date, ' ')" />
<xsl:variable name="day"   select="substring-after($date, ' ')" />
<xsl:variable name="time"  select="substring-after($dateTimeCondensed, ' ')" />
```

In the SharePoint Designer formula field, create a calculated formula on conditional formatting and associate this with the List items to be indicated as created over 7 days ago;

**=Created=+7**

Essentially you are talking "Calculated Columns" and the conditional formatting is based on XSL translations, as my list of xsl:variables describes. You might not be manually editing the XSL template but then again you may well be as what you have described in the above example appears to be XSLT.

SharePoint Designer 2010 you can add calculated columns and [formats are described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) for reference.

Hope this is of some help! :)